# Change store switcher select list into buttons

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, multistore

On [this multisite](https://www.gezondenotenkopen.nl) I have a store switcher (select list). Now I am able to switch between the stores and share the shopping cart. I want to change the select list in buttons.

My `storeswitcher.phtml` looks like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * @see Lucus_Foodisgood_Block_Storeswitcher
 * @var $this Lucus_Foodisgood_Block_Storeswitcher
 */
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function lucusStoreswitcher(obj) {
        var url = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value;
        window.location = url;
    }
</script>
<div class="lucus-store-switcher">
    <label for="lucus_store_switcher"><?php echo $this->__('Continue shopping at:') ?></label>
    <select title="><?php echo $this->__('Continue shopping at:') ?>" name="lucus_store_switcher" onchange="lucusStoreswitcher(this)">
        <?php foreach ($this->getStores() as $storeId => $store) : ?>
            <option <?php if ($this->isCurrentStore($storeId)) : ?>selected="selected"<?php endif ?> value="<?php echo $store['url'] ?>"><?php echo $store['name'] ?></option>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

How do I translate this into buttons/links:

```
<a href="" class="button">Shop 2</a> 
<a href="" class="button">Shop 3</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

copy `stores.phtml` from  app\design\frontend\base\default\template\page\switch

to `app\design\frontend\themepackage\theme\template\page\switch`

and replace with following code;

```
<?php if(count($this->getGroups())>1): ?>
<div class="store-switcher">
    <label for="select-store"><?php echo $this->__('Select Store:') ?></label>
<ul class="store-selector-ul">
<?php foreach ($this->getGroups() as $_group): ?>
<?php $_selected = ($_group->getId()==$this->getCurrentGroupId()) ? 'hide' : 'show' ?>
<li><a href="<?php echo $_group['home_url'];?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_group['name']);?></a></li>

<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```